# Is $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k)$ equivalent to countable additivity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The third axiom of probability theory, known as countable additivity, states that $$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(A_k)$$ holds for any countable sequence of disjoint events $A_1,A_2,\dots$.
How about the following one? Are they inequivalent? Why? $$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k)$$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? Do you know the definition of an infinite sum? How can you rewrite $P$ of a finite union of disjoint events?

Comment: They are equivalent, **if** you assume finite additivity. Otherwise, most likely not. To elaborate: You mention the “third axiom”, but there are more than one way to write up the axioms. I am used to having just the one you gave together with $P(\emptyset)=0$ and $P(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: … I forgot to mention $P(A)\ge0$ …

Comment: Are the $A_k$ supposed to be disjoint in the second equality? Otherwise it reminds me more of the continuity of $P$ from below (I hope that is the right term) meaning that if $(A_k)$ isa sequence of increasing sets, i.e. $A_k \subseteq A_{k+1}$, then $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) = \lim_{n\to \infty} P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n)$.

Comment: @GenericNickname: isn't it continuity from below regardless of whether $A_k$ are assumed to be disjoint or not?

Comment: @ilya only if $A_n$ are increasing.

Comment: @GenericNickname: well, their unions are increasing for sure.

Comment: @ilya that's right :)

Answer (score 3):

Not in general: the property that you've described is called the continuity from below. That is, if a set function $\mu:\Sigma \to \Bbb R$ is such that $\mu(\bigcup E_n) = \lim_n \mu(E_n)$ where $E_n\subseteq E_{n+1}$, then we say that it is continuous from below. In your case $E_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$.

As much as with usual functions, continuity does not imply additivity. For example, on a finite set any finite set function is continuous (since all infinite unions are finite unions), but of course there are set functions that are not measures, even on finite sets.